# align labels with calendar quarters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this simple example

```
tibble(date = c(ymd('2021-01-01'),
                ymd('2021-04-01')),
       value = c(10, 20)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

As you can see, the bar are centered at the `date`. Instead, I would like the first bar to span January to March (first quarter) and April to June (second quarter).

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: hi @akrun, thanks. unfortunately, the bar is still centered on january. I would like the tick to bar in January instead!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, we can adjust the `scale_x_date`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)   
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
start <- seq(min(tbl1$date), max(tbl1$date), by = '3 months')
end <- start %m+% months(2)
start_end <- str_c(format(start, '%b %Y'), format(end, '%b %Y'), sep='--')
tbl1 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = date %m+% days(40), y = value)) + 
      geom_col() + 
      scale_x_date(breaks = start, labels = start_end) + 
      xlab("date")
```

-output
[image]

#### data

```
tbl1 <- tibble(date = c(ymd('2021-01-01'),
                ymd('2021-04-01')),
       value = c(10, 20))
```

Comment: thanks Akrun but what is mean is for the label (say Jan-mar 2021) to be on the left side of the bar. Right now it is still on the center.. do you see what i mean?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Can you check if the update is what you wanted

Comment: nice! i wonder if playing with date_breaks and date_labels could avoid creating the start vector

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ yes, those vectors are created are from the vestige from earlier versions